# It's will be right ? for use < , > operator for compare date on php?

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

It's will be right ? for use `<` , `>` operator for compare date on php ?

I tested it. And it's work good. But i not founded documents for advice about use `<` , `>` operator for compare date on php.

Please tell me can we use `<` , `>` operator for compare date on php ?

```
<?PHP
$today = "2010-10-19";
$expired = "2012-12-10";

if($expired > $today)
{
    echo "not expired";
}
else
{
    echo "expired";
}
?>
```

Comment: The safe method would be using DateTime instances, by the way.

Comment: With this PHP does normal string comparison. This means the comparison only works, when the date is in the correct format to be compared from left to right. So it works for some cases, but I would recommend you to convert your dates into a timestamp and compare them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as your dates are in a comparable format this will work. Since they are compared as strings you need to make sure that the larger dates components are first and the smaller ones last. For example, the year, then the month, then the date. Always include leading zeros. That's what you do in your example so it works.

If you do not have the dates in this format your comparison will fail *some of the time*. For example:

```
'2016-07-04' > '2016-01-07' // true
'04-07-2016' > '07-01-2016' // false
```

The best way to compare dates is with [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) as DateTime objects are comparable and also account for all things date related like leap year and DST.

```
<?PHP
$today = new DateTime("2010-10-19");
$expired = new DateTime("2012-12-10");

if($expired > $today)
{
    echo "not expired";
}
else
{
    echo "expired";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** to convert datetime description into a Unix timestamp and you can easily compare timestamp with `<` or `>` operator

```
$today = strtotime('2010-10-19');// return 1287426600
$expired = strtotime('2012-12-10');// return 1355077800

if ($expired > $today) {// easily comparison of 1355077800 > 1287426600
    echo "not expired";
} else {
    echo "expired";
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain why exactly OP's code works and why exactly he should use `strtotime()` over his method.